# How can I make an unclickable HTML "Ghost" Div?

Tags: javascript, css, html, toast

Id like to make a Toast like div in HTML, that appears for a few seconds and eases out again, using css ease out.
The Problem is now, that it blocks clicking on stuff behind it while it is active and while it is invisible.
So is there a way to et the user click on stuff behind it?
I could just destroy it everytime it disapears, but then the ease effect is lost and the user still cant click on buttons while it is active.
So how do I make it more Google Toast like?

Comment: Can you set up a demo with what you currently have and what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: I like the idea of a toast div. What have you already tried? can we see some code?

Comment: wasnt my idea, i got it form this dude:http://blog.terrenceryan.com/android-toast-like-alerts-in-html-using-css/ I didnt really change too much to matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none`:

```
<div style="pointer-events: none">hi</div>
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle Using Button](http://jsfiddle.net/a8bXL/)</kbd>

Comment: +1 While your answer is working, we don't know yet what exactly the OP are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well pretty much this:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html anonymouss solution seams to work fine.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help.